# AJAX with Wordpress and OOP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin for Wordpress for automatically creating tables and populating them by pulling data from a database. To do this, I have created a class called "Table," and each Table object contains a query for the database that executes when the function "renderTable" is called. Each of the Table objects that an administrator has previousloy built are loaded when hooked into 'init':

```
function init_tables() {
global $wpdb;
// each row corresponds to a new tables metadata
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_delphi', ARRAY_A );

$tables = array();
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    $shortcode    = 'oracle_table_' . $row['id'];
    $select       = explode( ';', $row['table_select'] );
    $query_blocks = new QueryBlocks( $row['table_name'], $select, $row['table_order'] );
    $table        = new Table( $query_blocks );
    $form_metas   = json_decode( $row['table_forms'], true );
    foreach ( $form_metas as $form_meta ) {
        $table->addForm( $form_meta['type'], $form_meta['param'] );
    }
    add_shortcode( $shortcode, array( $table, 'render_table' ) );
    }
}

add_action('init', 'init_tables')
```

In addition to building and populating the table, the plugin is automating building forms related to different columns of the table. For form submittal, I use AJAX to communicate to the backend the data contained in the form:

```
app.post_ajax = function( serial_data ){
        serial_data += "&order_by=" + app.$active_order.attr('name') + "&order_mod=" + app.$active_order.attr('value');
        var post_data = {
            action     : 'table_query',
            nonce      : php_params.nonce,
            serialized : serial_data
        };

            $.post( php_params.ajax_url, post_data, app.ajax_response, 'json' )
    };
```

However, every time I press 'Submit', even though the function is an AJAX function, the constructor is run again and the entire object is rebuilt (which I'm guessing means the init hook is run again). Is this supposed to happen? Is there a way to persist data from the clientside to PHP and run my hooked AJAX php function without having to rebuild the entire object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an AJAX run in WP, the entire WP install "lifts" to serve / respond to that AJAX call.  All hooks and filter fire as they would normally, and basically, all plugins and theme functions run as they would for a normal page serve.

So - if there's something happening in your table `init` that you *do not* want to happen on an AJAX call (or honestly, in any function / file), then you need to check if it's an AJAX run, and prevent the code running (using the [wp_doing_ajax](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_ajax/) function).

For example (from your code, with modifications):

```
function init_tables() {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        return;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    // the rest of your function....
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! One more question. If I'm creating these table objects in the init function, will they exist after the AJAX run? (I don't think it will based on the result I'm seeing) Is there a way to make these tables exist throughout the lifetime of some user accessing the page (other than a SESSION variable)?

Comment: If you mean PHP objects, then no - not after the AJAX run.  If you want them to exist for entire access to a page, then you'll want them to be set up each lift in the `init` like you have it.  If by "entire access to a page", you mean _also available via AJAX_, then that's a different problem to solve.  Also, WP is not friendly to `$_SESSION` variables, so I'd strongly recommend using `$_COOKIE` - and be sure to read up on using cookies in WP.

Comment: thanks so much for the help, I'll upvote you the moment I have the rep to do it